# Schedule a Seminar in Minimum Time

Tags: algorithms, optimization, dynamic-programming, combinatorics, network-flow

There are t<sub>1</sub>, t<sub>2</sub>, t<sub>3</sub>,.....,t<sub>n</sub> topics which are to be scheduled in a building with c<sub>1</sub>,c<sub>2</sub>,c<sub>3</sub>,....c<sub>k</sub> halls. Members have already registered there interests on the topics, and they have liberty to choose any number of topics. There will be only one session on a given day per hall.

The problem is to finish the seminar in **minimum time** with as least as possible, members missing on their topics (so that we have most utilization of halls).

> My Solution:

For strictly no one missing on the topics there can be only one session on a day in only one hall and rest halls to be left unused. This takes longest possible time to finish the event. Only when all the k halls are utilized simultaneously, we can do it fastest.

Lets assume that t<sub>i</sub> is the set of all members interested in the i-th topic.

I am looking at a brute force solution in which we observe combinations of k topics (one topic per hall) to be scheduled at once. The effort is to find out intersection of groups in which cardinality of set with members choosing all those k-topics is minimum. Initially, there are <sup>n</sup>C<sub>k</sub> combinations, and after we schedule the first k-topics we can look for next <sup>n-k</sup>C<sub>k</sub> and then <sup>n-2k</sup>C<sub>k</sub>, <sup>n-3k</sup>C<sub>k</sub>... topics and so on.

As we see here, the main effort here is to find the intersection of k-sets. To me it looks like there should be some dynamic programming mechanism to reduce the repeated effort which I am unable to figure out. Do we have some thing absolutely different?

It is not a homework.

Comment: The problem is not well-specified: you list two different objective functions (minimum time, least members missing), and it is not clear how those should be traded off. We can't suggest algorithms if the problem isn't well-defined.  Please pick a single objective function you want to minimize, or otherwise specify how to resolve ambiguity between the two different optimization criteria.

Comment: @D.W. I thought with my workout it was sufficiently clear. We need to finish in minimum time (so as to save on costs of halls), but we also need to do it in such a way that the impact on participant members is minimum. I gave an example, in which I mentioned, to have zero conflict, we need to do every topic sequentially, which will make it longest possible event. We are rather looking for minimum time with least possible conflicts. Anyway, I edited it for more clarity.

Comment: No, I don't find it clear.  The way to do it with minimum time is to schedule all topics in parallel, but this has many people miss out.  The way to do it with minimum number of people missing out is to schedule sequentially, but this takes more time.  So, there is usually no way to meet both goals simultaneously.  You'll need to specify the problem in a way that defines how to trade off between those goals.  I don't see anything in the problem statement that does that.  I should not have to read your proposed solution to understand the task.

Comment: Perhaps you mean "schedule it with minimum time, and among all ways to do it with that amount of time, break ties in favor of solutions that reduce the number of people who miss out"?  If so, please [edit] the question to make that explicit.  There's no way I could infer that from the problem statement you listed.  Also can you credit the original source where you encountered this problem?  This might help us help you better, and might help others who are interested in the same problem find this question.